# Check that some letter belongs to Russian alphabet

Tags: utf-8, sas, string-function

I want to check that some letter belongs to Russian alphabet. I can do it with direct comparizon with Cyrillic letters:

```
letter in ('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Ж', ...)
```

Is there some simpler approach? E.g. for English alphabet I could use rank() function:

```
rank('A') <= rank(letter) <= rank('z')
```

But this function doesn't work for UTF-8 encoding. How can I get position of the letter in UTF-8 table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use the `BASECHAR` function.  This will convert the character to it's unicode escape.

```
data test;
input char $;
datalines;
Б
Г
Д
Ж
a
b
c
;
run;

data test;
set test;
ok = (char=basechar(char,'ESC'));
put char= ok=;
run;
```

Returns:

```
char=Б ok=0
char=Г ok=0
char=Д ok=0
char=Ж ok=0
char=a ok=1
char=b ok=1
char=c ok=1
```

Comment: This won't identify that the character is in the russian alphabet, though, right - just identify that it's not a character in the base encoding?  (Which may well work for the case at hand, just think it's worth mentioning what it's actually doing.)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to identify the raw bytecode with the `$HEX.` format, and then verify based on that (see a table like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) to see what values are Cyrillic).

For example, using Dom's example:

```
data test;
input char $;
put char= $HEX4.;
datalines;
Б
Г
Д
Ж
a
b
c
;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for advice Joe!